# How to configure HDFS CLI on a windows machine?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, command-line-interface, bigdata

There is a CLI tool which can be used on HDFS File System directly. Here is the GitHub [Link](https://github.com/avast/hdfs-shell)

I am using a windows machine and I use a Putty terminal to connect the HDFS in my Cluster. I came across the above git hub link and I want the HDFS CLI tool to be integrated with putty. I did go through the link and the Author has asked to configure couple of environmental variables to make this tool work. I am quite confused in configuring them.

I have downloaded the binary to my windows machine. Should I configure my Windows environmental variables? If I do so, how would this change affect the putty terminal as I use to connect my cluster from Putty.
Could any of you look into this and answer it in a detail to integrate the tool.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: See https://oyermolenko.blog/2017/01/25/first-blog-post about how to configure Putty and Environmental variables in custom cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putty is only a client. The CLI tool has to be downloaded and configured on the server to which you connect through Putty.

Login to the server using Putty, then

- Download the binary on the server along with the pre-requisites
- Follow the configuration steps based on the Server Operating System

Edit the `.bashrc` to update the classpath,

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/hbase-shell/lib/:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:$CLASSPATH
```

Comment: I have added the class path but still cant fire hdfs-shell.sh

Comment: What error do you get? and How are you executing it?

Comment: You have to add the path of the script location to the `PATH` variable like `export PATH=/location/of/script/:$PATH` in your `.bashrc` file or execute it directly.

Comment: Did it and got the below error
`[cloudera@quickstart hdfs-shell-1.0]$ PATH=/home/cloudera/hdfs-shell-1.0:$PATH
[cloudera@quickstart hdfs-shell-1.0]$ hdfs-shell.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/avast/server/hdfsshell/MainApp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)`

Comment: The pre-requisite is Java8. Looks like you have a lower version!

Comment: it worked after tweaking the environmental variables. @franklinsijo rocks!!